# Translating predicate definitions into English.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

First post, apologies if it's in the wrong format etc. I have this question from my lecturer and am really confused on how I would go about solving this. If anyone can provide any assistance or examples that would great.

Definitions of predicates:

V (x): x is a point (or vector).

L(x): x is a line.

X(x, y, z): the lines x and y intersect at point z.

P(x, z): z is a point on line x.

A(x, y, z): adding vector y to line x results in line z.

Based on these and also using the equality predicate = on vectors and lines;
~0 is the 0 vector. Translate the following into English.

1. ∀x. L(x) → ∃y. P(x, y)
2. ∀a. ∀b. ∀c. ∀d. (X(a, b, c) ∧ X(a, b, d)) → c = d ∨ a = b
3. ∀x. L(x) → ((∃y. V (y) ∧ P(x, y) ∧ A(x, y, x)) ↔ P(x,~0))

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  We are always looking for some effort on the part of you.  So: can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: What confuses me most is the variable. For example the practise question ∃x. ∃y. P(x, y).
I am unsure what to do with the y variable.

On some lines (x) there are....(y) how would I apply y?

Comment: OK, so take the first expression (which, by the way, is missing parentheses): $\forall x (L(x) \rightarrow P(x,y))$  The $forall x$ indicates that $L(x) \rightarrow P(x,y)$ is true for *all* $x$, i.e. for *every* object. So: for every object it is true that *if* it is a line, then $\exists y P(x,y)$.  OK, so what does that latter part say? Here, the $\exists y$ indicates that there is *some* object for which $P(x,y)$ is true, i.e. for which $y$ is a point on $x$. So, filling this in, we get: for every object it is true that *if* it is a line, then there is some object that is a point on x ....

Comment: ...(continued) Now that is a very unnatural statement, but you can paraphrase it like this: for every line x, there is some object that is a point on x .  And that can be further simplified to:  Every line has a point on it. ... does that help?

Comment: That one makes sense but I still don't fully grasp the concept. In the practise question ∃x. ∃y. P(x, y). You've got ∃x stating there is some object which is true as you stated but what about the ∃y. Would it simply be Some lines have points on them?

Comment: So technically, it would be 'There is some object x such that there is some object y such that y is a point on s' ... which rephrased would indeed be 'some line(s) have some point(s) on them'. (The (s) is to emphasize that $\exists$ is looking for 'one or more')

Comment: Right, that makes a load more sense. The variables were confusing me as I kept referring to the definitions and was confused by the difference. Thank you so much, think I'll be able to manage the rest now, just had to be sure before I started.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Nice work, @Bram28!  If you summarize (or copy) your comments and post them as an answer,  **please ping me** and I'll upvote it.  You can even post the answer noting that @amWhy insisted that you do so.  I will soon delete this comment, in the hopes you'll post your explanations as an answer.

Comment: And, nice work @TheGrind.  If every asker would be as responsive to comments, and interaction in the comments, I would be in heaven.

Comment: @Bram28 No...I can manage text in Mathjax, but I'm a worthless source to consult for plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the first expression (which, by the way, is missing parentheses):

$$\forall x (L(x) \rightarrow P(x,y))$$

The $\forall x$ indicates that $L(x) \rightarrow P(x,y)$ is true for all $x$, i.e. for every object. So, it says

$$\text{"For every object it is true that if it is a line, then $\exists y P(x,y)$"}$$

OK, so what does that latter part say? Here, the $\exists y$ indicates that there is some object $y$ for which $P(x,y)$ is true, i.e. for which $y$ is a point on $x$. So, filling this in, we get:

$$\text{"For every object $x$ it is true that if it is a line, then there is some object $y$ that is a point on $x$"}$$

Now that is a very unnatural statement, but you can paraphrase it like this:

$$\text{"For every line $x$, there is some object that is a point on $x$"}$$

And that can be further simplified to:

$$\text{"Every line has a point on it"}$$

You also mention:

$$\exists x \exists y P(x,y)$$

This translates to:

$$\text{"There is some object $x$ such that there is some object $y$ such that $y$ is a point on $x$}$$

... which rephrased would indeed be

$$\text{"Some line(s) have some point(s) on them"}$$

(The (s) is to emphasize that $\exists y$  is looking for 'one or more')